# iOS - How To Align UIAlertActions Properly?

Tags: ios, uialertaction

I am adding a checkmark to the item selected by the user in UIAlertController(ActionSheetStyle). However, once the checkmark is added, the item with the checkmark is not aligned properly with the other items.

Since the items are center-aligned it will look like this:

```
 Item AAA
Item BBB ✓
 Item CCC
```

I want them to be like this:

```
Item AAA
Item BBB ✓
Item CCC
```

So what I tried is I added spaces at the end of the labels with no checkmark. But still it has no effect on the alignment.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try to add 2 space character       `  Item BBB ✓`

Comment: As what I mentioned, I already tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some invisible unicode symbols.

Comment: I thought of doing this also. But honestly, I don't think this is a good solution.